# Примеры веб-приложений react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Какие есть примеры веб-приложений на react.js? Где можно посмотреть на что он способен в работающем состоянии?

Comment: _Что нужно, чтобы начать изучать react.js?_ - нужно желание, _для чего он вообще нужен_ - нужен для написания web-приложений.

Comment: Вам поможет этот список: https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Sites-Using-React

Comment: `Где можно посмотреть на что он способен в работающем состоянии?` - открываете facebook - смотрите, изучаете)